# Passing the parameters to SQL Server report server link and download the Pdf report via R Shiny app throwing error HTTP status was '401 Unauthorized

Tags: r, shiny, reporting-services, httr, httr2

The below code auto downloads the report file after passing the variables but I want to save the file to a specific path and view the same in UI also.

```
library(shiny)
library(httr2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  dateInput("startDate", "Start Date"),
  dateInput("endDate", "End Date"),
  textInput("rn", "Report Number"),
  actionButton("runReport", "Run Report"),
  uiOutput("reportOutput")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$runReport, {
    startDate <- input$startDate
    endDate <- input$endDate
    reportNumber <- input$rn
    
    # Generate the report URL with the variables
    reportURL <- paste0("http://localhost/ReportServer?%2fReport1",
                        "&StartDate=", format(startDate, "%Y-%m-%d"),
                        "&EndDate=", format(endDate, "%Y-%m-%d"),
                        "&rn=", reportNumber,
                        "&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF&rc:LinkTarget=_self"
    )
    
    output$reportOutput <- renderUI({
      # Render the iframe with the dynamically generated source filename
      tags$iframe(style = "width: 100%; height: 500px", src = reportURL)
    })



response <- httr2::request(reportURL) 
    # Perform the request
    result <- httr2::req_perform(response)
    
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I tried updating the code with download.file function like shown below but didn't worked out

```
# Generate the report URL with the variables
    reportURL <- paste0("http://desktop-lgjc8bc/ReportServer?%2fReport1",
                        "&StartDate=", format(startDate, "%Y-%m-%d"),
                        "&EndDate=", format(endDate, "%Y-%m-%d"),
                        "&rn=", reportNumber,
                        "&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF&rc:LinkTarget=_self"
    )
    
    saveDir <- "D:/Projects/Report1.pdf"  # Replace with the desired directory path

    
    # Save the report to the specified directory
    download.file(reportURL, saveDir, mode = "wb")
```

i tried with httr and httr2 library packages also. All throwing same error **HTTP status was '401 Unauthorized**

please share your thoughts and workarounds for this. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm fairly sure that SQL Server does not factor in the solution you need.

Comment: 'HTTP status was '401 Unauthorized' is the error i am getting

Comment: Then [edit] that into your question